# Show on click, but hide on mouseout - not working?

Tags: jquery, css, mouseevent, slidetoggle

I'm ALMOST there with this issue, but have hit a wall.

I have a main nav list that shows dropdown content on hover, and then when you click the parent link, it needs to reveal a new div of content in place of the original dropdown. I've got that working. HOWEVER, I need the new div to disappear when you mouseout of the parent `<li>`. This is where the problem starts. No matter what I do, it seems to be acting when you mouseout from the link, instead of the `<li>`.

**Here is a fiddle to see what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/nWxdR/25/**

Click "about" to show the blue div. Then after you roll your mouse off the words, you lose the blue div. I want the blue div to stay until you roll off of the entire `<li>` - not the link.

(Note: The gap between the main link and the sublinks is supposed to be there -- there's going to be a background image there.)

I'm grateful for any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event instead of mouseout.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWxdR/25/)

```
$(".about").mouseleave(function() { 
    $("#about-text").hide();
});
```

From jQuery's docs -

> The mouseleave event differs from mouseout in the way it handles event
>   bubbling. If mouseout were used in this example, then when the mouse
>   pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseleave event,
>   on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the
>   element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the
>   handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the Outer element, but not
>   the Inner element.

Comment: Yep - mouseleave worked! I'm glad it was that easy to fix. Though it's simplicity makes the time I spent trying to figure it out much more embarrassing. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`slidetoggle()` will animate the text in on mouse over and out again on mouse out. change this to `.show()` or animated reveal of your choice. Combine this with the answer given above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this particular case, slidetoggle() is doing what I want, but you are correct that mouseleave did indeed fix my problem.